# How to get Elastic Beanstalk to send notifications for all log messages?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic Beanstalk notifications to an SNS topic do not send all the log messages.

For example when deploying a new version, it only sends:

"New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances."

However I don't get messages like this even though they seem to be the same log level:

"Environment update is starting."

"Environment update completed successfully."

Is there a way to rig it to send all logged messages, or do I have to do that with some CloudWatch alert?

Comment: Same here, only some of the events are reported...

Answer (score 0):

Messages like "Environment update is starting" and "Environment update completed successfully" should appear on your console in Elastic Beanstalk. Are you saying you never see this event messages? Is it possible that they scroll past very fast in your console?
These events are archived so you can click on "Show all" in the console to see old events. You can also use the [DescribeEvents API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_DescribeEvents.html) to get archived messages for your environment.

Comment: I see all messages in the console. I want to get them as notifications (to an SNS topic) but it only sends "New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances."

Comment: I see ... currently you can receive notifications for only some events